# Php, give current generated id to this meeting users?

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am working with full Calendar. In this i need when meeting is created successfully i need this meeting id from database table and apply this id to users which selected for this meeting.

i didn't need to do this with any php like mysqli_insert_id etc. I need id in response.

I am stuck on this point. Please help if any one know about this.

Yes, i didn't know how to get meeting id and apply this to users. I mean to say, if i create 5 meetings in one day and i need users by meeting. For this i need to give meeting id for every meeting users.

Here is my code please see and suggest you good ideas.

Php Code.

```
function create_meetings($activeUserId , $title , $start , $des , $meetingName){
    echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `meetings`(`id`,`name` , `description` , `user_id` , `meeting_date_time` , `date_created` , `date_modified` , `status`) VALUES(NULL, '".$title."' , '".$des."',  ".$activeUserId." , '".$start."' , CURDATE() , '' , 'A')";
    if ($GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully.";
    }else{
        echo 'Problem While inserting meeting attendance.';
    }
}
```

JavaScript Code.

```
function getUsers(depId){
            var data = { 'action': 'getUserDep', 'depId': depId};
            $.post("php/users.php", data).success(function (resp) {
                //console.log(resp);
                var json = $.parseJSON(resp);
                var outPut = '';
                var di = '';
                var id = '';
                var name = "";
                for(i in json){
                    di = json[i].dep_id;
                    id = json[i].id;
                    name = json[i].name;
                    outPut +="<li value="+id+" class='ui-widget-content name' id='name'><span class='di' style='display:none;'>"+di+"</span>"+name+" <div class='tick gray-tick pull-right' style='padding:10px; '></div></li>";
                }
                $('#selectable').html(outPut);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $('.img').hide();
                $('#myInput').hide();
                $('#selectUsers , #manageUsers').click(function(){
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(date).format();
                    var userid = $(this).val();
                    var title = copiedEventObject.title;
                    var cb = sessionStorage.activeUserId;
                    var des = $('#meeting_description').val();
                    var meetingName = $('#meetingName').val();
                    //console.log(title + " " + start);
                    var mData = { 'action': 'meetings', 'title': title , 'start': start , 'activeUserId': cb , 'des':des , 'meetingName': meetingName};
                    $.post('php/users.php' , mData).success(function(resp){
                        alert(resp);
                        $('#selectable').show();
                        $('#meeting').hide();
                        $('#selectUsers').hide();
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
                    });
                });
                $('.name').click(function(){
                    $(this).find('.tick').toggleClass('green-tick');
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(date).format();
                    alert(start);
                    var dep = $(this).find('.di').text();
                    var userid = $(this).val();
                    var cb = sessionStorage.activeUserId;
                    //alert(start + " " + dep + " " + userid);
                    //console.log(title + " " + start);
                    var MP_Data = { 'action': 'meeting_participants', 'dep': dep , 'activeUserId': cb , 'userid': userid};
                    $.post('php/users.php' , MP_Data).success(function(resp){
                        alert(resp);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        getUsers();
```

Comment: Can you explain where it fails / where you are stuck?

Comment: Yes, i didn't know how to get meeting id and apply this to users. I mean to say, if i create 5 meetings in one day and i need users by meeting. For this i need to give meeting id for every meeting users.

Comment: Please copy/paste your comment into your question and delete the comment.  This will help everyone to see what you have to say without reading all the comments.

Comment: why can't you return the id in response?

Comment: Because i am new to use php. That's why i didn't get id in response.

Comment: Please help me.